# Aggregate vs value initializing an aggregate class object with padding

Tags: c++, c++14, padding

Aggregate initialization initializes the data members of an aggrete class object, whereas value initialization of an aggregate will first zero initialize it which *also zeroes out padding bytes*, as shown by the following spec quote

> if T is a (possibly cv-qualified) non-union class type, each non-static data member and each base-class subobject is zero-initialized and padding is initialized to zero bits;

Does this mean that generally one should avoid initializing aggregate structs using `()` and prefer `{}` instead because the latter doesn't have to ensure that padding bits are zero?

If the answer to the above is "no", are there cases where implementations don't fill padding with `{}` but do with `()`? And among these cases, what is the better choice to use for the programmer?

Comment: [Clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e30e266d90c16662) does respect the rule, while [gcc](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/eff8609fc153d914) and MSVC still zeroes out padding bytes in my test.

Answer (score 1):

No.  Firstly, I suspect that most compilers will actually value initialize an aggregate (given constant arguments) with a single value (including padding) *anyway*.

However the important reason why not, is that this sort of micro-optimization should be left until you have measurements which show there is a problem (and I bet you will never get those measurements).  In the meantime, write whichever is the clearest.

Comment: Thanks. My question is updated accordingly. Why have you restricted your agument to single-member aggregates? Do implementations behave differently if the structs contain multiple.members with possibly multiple inter member padding?

Comment: I didn't mean just single-member aggregates.  I would expect `struct A { char c; short s; long long ll};` to be initialized with a single 128 or 256-bit value (given constant arguments), not three separate values.